# algorithm/library for text similarity

Tags: c++, algorithm, text

I need to implement algorithm (or find one in an open source library) for evaluation of text similarities. I need an efficient algorithm for given two arbitrary sets of documents (relatively small number of big chunks of text) it to create a matching pairs between them - which document is most likely to be produced from which one.

I believe I will split this in two - defining the similarity coefficient of every pair - and then applying some of the assignment problem algorithms. While for the assignment algorithms I can find a good number of solutions I cannot find a good one for the computing the similarity coefficients.

Note the documents are not known in advance - computing indexes of the text (if there is) must be fast as well.

I am aware of Hamming distance, Levenshtein distance some of the other algorithms for string difference. This is not what I am looking for though - I am using the word text instead string on purpose.

I am not looking for phrase search algorithms as well what libraries like Lucene and Xapian are made for (at least seems to be).

Probably something based on tf–idf.

I guess the question is, is there something that already solves this problem or is it possible libraries like lucete to be used to do that.

Comment: Maybe you could use a slightly modifies version of the longest common subsequence algorithm, which is used in the linux `diff` command. More info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: yes, this is an option. Unfortunately it seems overly expensive performance wise because it needs to be done independently for every pair. I am hoping to find something that will reduce the complexity per pair comparison based on some form of indexing. thanks

Comment: You might want to look at a [paper by Coeurjolly, Drouilhet and Robineau](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604246v2.pdf). I found it quite useful the last time I worked on something like this (though it was quite new at the time -- there may be better papers now).

Comment: The Levenstein Distance algorithm is available on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do as a starting point (just because it is simple and fast):

- Map the words to numbers using a shared map or hash_map
- For each text, build the corresponding map of word-level trigram counts
- Compare the overlap

We can assume that the dictionary size is < 1m (or 21bit), so we can just encode a trigram in an int64.

```
void CountTrigrams(const vector<string>& words, 
                   map<string, int> * dict, 
                   map<int64, int> * result) {
  int64 trigram = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
    const& word = words[i];
    int id;
    auto di = dict->find(word);
    if (di == dict->end()) {
      id = dict.size();
      dict[word] = id;
    } else {
      id = di->second;
    }
    trigram = ((trigram << 21) | id) & 0x7fffffffffffffff;
    if (i > 2) {
      auto ti = result->find(trigram);
      if (ti == result->end()) {
        result[trigram] = 1;
      } else {
        ti->second++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then compare the results for each pair:

```
int Compare(const map<int64, int> & t1, const map<int64, int> & t2) {
  int score = 0;
  for (auto i = t1.first(); i != t1.end(); i++) {
    auto j = t2.find(t1->first);
    if (j != t2.end()) {
      score += MAX(i->second, j->second);
    }
  }
  return score;
}
```

It may make sense to normalize the score somehow, e.g. divide by the total number of trigrams.